# C# - Parsing tool for the DOT Language

Tags: c#, graphviz

I have a .dot file and I need to use c# to generate an image for the DOT Language file. Is there any tool can help me to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: @user523774 It is important on StackOverflow to accept answers (with the tick next to the answer), if they are satisfactory solutions to your question.

Answer (score 2):

[This DOT grammar](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/grammars/index.htm) for Gold Parser allows you to parse a .DOT file.

To actually produce images, you can use DOT, NEATO, etc from [AT&T Graphiz](http://www.graphviz.org)

If you want to do it in Visio, [my addin for Visio](http://www.calvert.ch/graphvizio/) is a free option (and a shameless plug). BTW, it's [open source](http://graphvizio.sourceforge.net/)

A word of friendly advice: parsing DOT is relatively easy; making the results into a picture is considerably harder.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't real need to parse a dot file, all I need is to generate an image from a dot file. I already have the .dot file.

Comment: Then DOT/NEATO/etc are the only solution

Comment: The DOT grammar link no longer works. While I can get some results on Google I'm not sure they are the right things for programmatically parsing/rendering .dot files in C#.

Comment: You can find the DOT grammar at http://www.goldparser.org/grammars/index.htm it's labelled 'Graphviz', 2/3 the way down the page

Answer (score 0):

There are several NuGet packages that does this. For example [DotBuilder](https://bitbucket.org/tobyrogers/dotbuilder/src/master/) by Toby Rogers which will let you build a graph and render it using your graphviz installation like this:

```
    var gv = new GraphViz(@"C:\Develop\Tools\graphviz\bin", OutputFormat.Svg);
    using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\artifacts\dotbuilder\test.svg", FileMode.Create))
    {
        gv.RenderGraph(graph, stream);
    }
```

What it does for the rendering is really just a command line call to the graphviz binary which you could also do directly from your own code if you prefer to not use third-party tool.